# Hard drive preventing Windows to start

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot

I have an internal SATA hard drive and used only for data storage (audio and videos). It's usually used on my media player but sometimes I take it out and installed on my PC for transferring files.

It's just work fine that way until yesterday. 
My Windows 7 won't boot and stuck at "Verifying DMI pool data" while the hard drive was attached. If I take it out the Windows back to boot normally. 
I have tried to replace the SATA cable but Windows still stuck. So I thought may be the hard drive was faulty. I checked in BIOS and it's detected just fine. I use Hiren Boot CD to boot and use some hard drive testing tools in it including Checkdisk and it's just fine. I ran Mini Windows XP tools and it's detected just fine in Windows Explorer. I can browse it's folder. Copying files. Pasting new files etc. No sign of slow read or write. And if I put it back into my media player it's just working fine. I can't figure out  why it's preventing Windows from starting. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue before.
My fix was to go to the BIOS/UEFI to change the boot order of the HDD to the top.